# php-return null value at client side but get data at server side

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

client side can get the value if i put the query code at server not in model.here is my code:

```
  function player_item(){

       $CI =& get_instance();
       $CI->db->select('player_item, count(*) as total',false);
       $CI->db->from('rps'); 
       $CI->db->group_by('player_item');
       $query = $CI->db->get();

       $data= $query->result_array();
       return json_encode($data);
    }
```

when i change to MVC approach and try to print out the value at client side, it return null value.here is my code:

Model:

```
function get_player_item()
  {
      $this->db->select('player_item, count(*) as total');
      $this->db->from('rps'); 
      $this->db->group_by('player_item');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $rows = array();
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
       {
          $rows[] = $row;
        }
       return $rows;
}
```

server:

```
function player_item()

    {
           $CI =& get_instance();
           $CI->load->model("player");
           $data=$CI->player->get_player_item();
           return json_encode($data);
     }
```

Client:

```
 $result = $this->nusoap_client ->call('player_item');
 $data['player'] = json_decode($result, true);
 var_dump($data['player'] );
```

What wrong with my code? i can get the value when print_r(json_encode($data)) at server.`string(112) "[{"player_item":"paper","total":"9"},{"player_item":"rock","total":"10"},{"player_item":"scissors","total":"8"}]"`

Comment: json_decode returns null when the json string you are trying to decode is not in proper JSON format. what is in $result?

Comment: var_dump($result) return bool(false)

Comment: try the answer below.

Comment: Can you make sure the "nusoap_client" is get the function ?

Answer (score 0):

As your script does not generate any actual output, the client side will see nothing.

You need to change this:

```
{
       $CI =& get_instance();
       $CI->load->model("player");
       $data=$this->player->get_player_item();
       return json_encode($data);
}
```

to:

```
{
       $CI =& get_instance();
       $CI->load->model("player");
       $data=$this->player->get_player_item();
       echo json_encode($data);
       ^^^^ Make your script output the json instead of returning it
}
```

Comment: @khalidas You should check (using cURL / browser / etc.) if the server-side is outputting the right data. If it is (it seems it should now...), the problem is on the client side.